# How to compare two lists with different lengths and remove some elements?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, the first contains some elements that don't exist in the second list which have more elements. I need to delete elements that don't exist in the second list.

In the example below, I need to delete just the '0' from the first list.
So:

```
Input:
list1 = [0,1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Output:
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I tried this simple code but it return an empty list

```
list1=[0,1,2,3]
list2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for element in list1:
    for element1 in list2:
        if element != element1:
            for element in list1:
                list1.remove(element)
print(list1)
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sets to do this!

```py
set(list1).intersection(list2) # [1,2,3]
```

You can also use list comprehension but it's slower in theory.

```py
list1 = [0,1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

list1 = [x for x in list1 if x in list2] # [1,2,3]
```